# MudAutocomplete, making some items selectable and some others not

Tags: autocomplete, blazor, mudblazor

I'm creating a blazor component using the **MudAutocomplete** component.
So far it's working as expected, but I need to set some items as selectable and some others not selectable.

For example, I have **categories** and **items**, each item belongs to a category. So I need to select only the items in the category no the category itself. Is there a way I can accomplish that?
I've been searching in the docs and I haven't found anything yet regarding **events** on **selection**, just boolean values.

Basically I created a data structure for modeling the categories and items (n-ary tree), and each item contains a prop called **isSelectable** besides title and Id. The render of the component is just fine, I have a autocomplete component with nested items, but all of them are selectable. I only need to select the **leaves**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the `ItemDisabledFunc` attribute on the component.

```
<MudAutoComplete T="YourType" 
                 Label="Item" 
                 @bind-Value="YourModel.SelectedItem" 
                 ItemDisabledFunc="IsDisabled"></MudAutoComplete>

@code {
    private bool IsDisabled(YourType item)
    {
        return !item.isSelectable;
    }
}
```